# How to Group a table and get results for a row based on the previous rows' data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lookup table that relates dates and people associated with those dates:

```
id, user_id,date
1,1,2014-11-01
2,2,2014-11-01
3,1,2014-11-02
4,3,2014-11-02
5,1,2014-11-03
```

I can group these by date(day):

```
  SELECT    DATE_FORMAT(
                MIN(date),
                '%Y/%m/%d 00:00:00 GMT-0'
            ) AS date,
            COUNT(*) as count
    FROM    user_x_date
GROUP BY    ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) / 43200)
```

But, how can get the number of unique users, that have now shown up previously? For instance this would be a valid result:

```
unique, non-unique, date
2,0,2014-11-01
1,1,2014-11-02
0,1,2014-11-03
```

Is this possibly without having to rely on a scripting language to keep track of this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will do what you want, at least it seems to work for your limited sample data.

The idea is to use a correlated sub-query to check if the user_id has occurred on a date before the date of the current row and then do some basic arithmetic to determine number of unique/non-unique users for each date.

Please give it a try.

```
select 
  sum(u) - sum(n) as "unique", 
  sum(n) as "non-unique", 
  date 
from (
  select 
    date, 
    count(user_id) u, 
    case when exists (
      select 1 
      from Table1 i
      where i.user_id = o.user_id 
        and i.date < o.date
    ) then 1 else 0 
    end n
  from Table1 o
  group by date, user_id
) q
group by date
order by date;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad904/3)

I didn't include the `id` column in the sample fiddle as it's not needed (or used) to produce the result and won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant question:  "But, how can get the number of unique users, that have now shown up previously?"

Calculate the first time a person shows up, and then use that for the aggregation:

```
SELECT date, count(*) as FirstVisit
FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(date) as date
      FROM user_x_date
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) x
GROUP BY date;
```

I would then use this as a subquery for another aggregation:

```
SELECT v.date, v.NumVisits, COALESCE(fv.FirstVisit, 0) as NumFirstVisit
FROM (SELECT date, count(*) as NumVisits
      FROM user_x_date
      GROUP BY date
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT date, count(*) as FirstVisit
      FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(date) as date
            FROM user_x_date
            GROUP BY user_id
           ) x
      GROUP BY date
     ) fv
     ON v.date = fv.date;
```